# SQL count products

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot, oracle12c

I have table:

```
name    product
john     beer
john     milk
john     tea
john     beer
emily    milk
emily    milk
emily    tea
john     beer
```

i need select from this table, when output will be:

```
name count(tea)  count(beer) count(milk)  count(total)
john    1             3          1              5
emily   1             0          2              3
```

any idea how to do this?

DB: oracle 12

Comment: What's the expected result if someone suddenly inserts (matt, coffee)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select name
    sum(case when product = 'tea' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_tea,
    sum(case when product = 'beer' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_beer,
    sum(case when product = 'milk' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_milk,
    count(*) total
from mytable
group by name
```

Depending on your database, there may be neater options available to express the conditional counts.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
You helped me a lot.